# How to extend Springboot logback configuration? (default.xml apparently not available)

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I am trying to follow [the Springboot logback customisation instructions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging).

I want to obtain basically the default behaviour (so I can then add it it).

That page says:

```
A typical custom logback.xml file would look something like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/default.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

... so I tried that, and I get

> WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.IncludeAction - Could not
>   find resource corresponding to
>   [org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/default.xml]

I have this lot in my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging',
```

... in theory I think starter-web on its own should be enough?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems to be a typo in the documentation.

The file is present in the `spring-boot-X.X.X.jar` file, but it's named `defaults.xml`, not `default.xml`.

[image]